# Create Horizontal Line in Excel Chart with Macro

Tags: excel, charts, line

At work, I have made a macro to format and chart out data that comes from testing the parts we make. The values have to be within a certain range, so I would like to add lines to the charts denoting where the tolerance limits are.

For example, one parameter is a voltage value for a certain signal. It must be between .271 and .451 to be in spec, so I would like to add lines at those values on that chart.

Other charts are measuring different things and would have different values, but the basic principle is the same.

The number of data points per signal is not the same, but is usually quite large, around a couple thousand each.

I have found a couple of different options around the internet involving the drawing tools or adding a new data series to the charts, but I am not well versed in those aspects of excel macros. In fact, I don't think I can find the page that I first found the data series idea at.

Comment: I would use a separate data series for each line: you only need two points to create the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new series for each line is the best approach.

```
 'add a line series with line but no markers
    Sub AddLineSeries(cht As ChartObject, sName As String, xvals, _
                       yvals, SeriesColor As Long)
        Dim s As Series
        Set s = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With s
            .Name = sName
            .Values = yvals
            .XValues = xvals
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = xlNone
            .MarkerForegroundColor = SeriesColor
            .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
            With .Border
                .Weight = xlThin
                .Color = SeriesColor
            End With
        End With
    End Sub
```

Usage (adding one line for each cut-off):

```
'cht is the chart object
'minX/maxX are x-axis values you want to plot the line for
'qcMin/Max are the y-axis values for your lower/upper cut-offs
'Array() just creates an array of values to pass to the chart for plotting, since
'   we're not using values from a worksheet for this series
AddLineSeries cht, "QC Min", Array(minX, maxX), Array(qcMin, qcMin), _
              RGB(255, 0, 0)
AddLineSeries cht, "QC Max", Array(maxX, maxX), Array(qcMax, qcMax), _
              RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: cht is the chart that I'm modifying to add the lines too

Comment: Woops, posted too early, I'll do one better in a bit

Comment: I get most of it except for the arrays. They are representing the X and Y values, but do they need to be created or are those lines enough? maxIndex, I assume, is the amount of data points that I have, but what are qcMin and qcMax? My upper and lower tolerances? Do you have a link for documentation on that Array() function?

Comment: .XValues = Array(7, used_rows) does not work. Method 'XValues' of object 'Series' failed. The first 6 rows of the columns are header information, so the data starts in row 7. Am I supposed to put 7 or 1 there?

Comment: The same happens for the Values array too.

Comment: BTW, I forgot to mention that I am using Excel 2007, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm using excel 2007 too.  If you want to send your workbook I will take a look (timjwilliams at gmail dot com): hard to say what's the issue otherwise...

Comment: I can't give you the actual data since it's company property, but I'll play around some more when I have time and see if I can make it work.

Comment: After an email converstion with Tim, I made the chart a scatter plot instead of a line and it worked perfectly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an XY Scatter chart, just create a couple of data points and add it as a new series. For example, enter your data as shown in A1:B6 and then add that entire range as a series. You'll get two lines. Obviously, the X and Y values should be calculated from your original data.

[image]

Comment: It's not just one chart. the data set I'm using has 36 charts that are automatically created by the macro. Furthermore, I want other people who run this test to be able to use it without having to do a lot of manual formatting themselves.

Comment: @Mark, you can implement this in VBA as well, or have it already set up in your workbook (maybe with the calculations on a hidden sheet). The point that I was trying to make is that you really only need one series for multiple lines. It is all in how you set up the data.